# Добавление новых объектов в массив в Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

В payload приходит массив с объектами у которых есть общий индентификатор.

Не получается проверить, есть ли такие объекты в стейте. если нет то добавить в текущее состояние стейта, есть присутствуют, то игнорировать их

```
  case GET_COMMENTS_SUCCESS:
      let comarr = state.comments.some(
        (item: CommentsType) => item.postId === payload
      );
      if (!comarr) {
        state = {
          ...state,
          comments: [...state.comments, ...payload],
          loadingComments: false,
        };
      } else {
        state = {
          ...state,
          comments: payload,
          loadingComments: false,
        };
      }

      break;
```

Comment: Если у вас в стейте несколько элементов и приходят новые и вам надо добавить только "уникальные", то делайте примерно так: `payload.forEach(el => { if (!state.comments.find(i => i.postId === el.postId)) state.comments.push(el)})`

Answer (score 0):

решил сам, надо было сделать проверку по индексу

```
  case GET_COMMENTS_SUCCESS:
      let comarr = state.comments.some(
        (item: CommentsType) => item.postId === **payload.indexOf(item.postId)**
      );
      if (!comarr) {
        state = {
          ...state,
          comments: [...state.comments, ...payload],
          loadingComments: false,
        };
      } else {
        state = {
          ...state,
          comments: payload,
          loadingComments: false,
        };
      }

      break;
```